# display picture gallery efficiently using PHP

Tags: php, html, server

Using PHP I have written code to display images on the server to the website.

```
<div class="gallery">
        <?php foreach (scandir("assets/images/gallery/") as $key => $value) { ?>
          <?php if (preg_match('/[\s\S]+\.(png|jpg|jpeg)/', $value)) { ?>
            <div class="grid-img">
              <a href='assets/images/gallery/<?= $value ?>' rel="rel1" class="big">
                <img class="grid-item_img" rel="rel1" src='assets/images/gallery/<?= $value ?>'>
              </a>
            </div>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
      </div>
```

This code does a scan in the `assets/images/gallery/` directory and if a picture format is matched `png, jpg or jpeg` the image is displayed in the gallery.

Now my problem is not with the code itself, it actually works and has no errors, but I feel like this isn't a very efficient approach to display images. If I have 100+ images on the server then all of them are loaded at the same time, causing a slow website.

How can I improve this code to be more viable on the website, so that a user doesn't get an unresponsive website because 100+ images are loading on the site? Is there a much more efficient way to do this?

The only solution I have is to maybe have the images hosted on an image hosting site, but I don't want these images to be hosted on a third-party website, because I want the admin to upload images to the server and have control over them.

Any tips are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: you could return the list of files in an array and then use `array_chunk` to break into more manageable numbers

Comment: I don't think this is inefficient code, if read off a filesystem.  Of course it depends on what you want to have, but a server with sufficient memory will buffer the files.  If displaying 300 files is too much data, then introduce some form of pagination.  Caching the scandir results for the purposes of counts would be a helpful optimization, and you could use php session variables for that, or some other caching system that allows you to persist data between requests (memcache,redis, apc, shmop, read/write a file) .  I would start by just doing something basic with the array count.

Comment: @gview that sounds like a good idea, pagination might be a good solution to achieve some optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead to only select the files that match the pattern:

```php
<?php foreach (glob("assets/images/gallery/*.{png,jpg,jpeg}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) { ?>
    <div class="grid-img">
        <a href='<?php echo $filename ?>' rel="rel1" class="big">
            <img class="grid-item_img" rel="rel1" src='<?php echo $filename ?>'>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

This does not help the client download faster. For that you could try preloading the images, or a higher upload speed using a fileserver e.g. Amazon S3.

Answer (score 0):

For the question

> How can I improve this code to be more viable on the website, so that a user doesn't get an unresponsive website because 100+ images are loading on the site? Is there a much more efficient way to do this?

1. pagination to limit number of max number of images per page
2. having thumbs of target images & showing them to the user for him/her to select for the higher resolution
3. if possible and tons of images to scan, consider having subfolders named like jpegs, pngs etc.
4. Cron job may help to perform scandir process time to time so you may have the chance to make just a single query which was written to your DB in the cron job

it's not possible to increase the visitor's download speed but bullets above help to decrease total duration to complete the page download.

Comment: With the `<picture>` element you can provide different thumbs for different screen sizes (c.f.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images)